# handle json in python post request and response in django

Tags: python, json, django, python-2.7, request

We are trying to make a post request to django api using requests package in python.

**Request:**

```
d = {"key1":"123", "key2":[{"a":"b"},{"c":"d"}]}

response = requests.post("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/postapi/",data=d)
```

At the server end we are trying to get the parameters using the below code.

```
def handle_post(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        key1 = request.POST.get('key1', '')
        key2 = request.POST.get('key2', '')
        print key1,type(key1)
        print key2,type(key2)
        return JsonResponse({'result': 'success'}, status=200)
```

I am trying to get the values in key1 and key2.

**Expected output:**

```
123,<type 'unicode'>
[{"a":"b"},{"c":"d"}], <type 'list'>
```

**Actual output:**

```
123 <type 'unicode'>
c <type 'unicode'>
```

How can we get the expected output in django ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `getlist` for key2.

```
key2 = request.POST.getlist('key2', '')
```

But you might find it easier to send the data as JSON and access `json.loads(request.body)`.

Comment: using getlist in key2 gave [u'a', u'c'] <type 'list'> rather than the entire dict